# Posfijo a arbol y despues a pila C++

Tags: c++, árboles, pilas

Estoy tratando de hacer el siguiente pseudocodigo

*Pseudocodigo:*

```
Algoritmo-Posfija-Árbol
INICIO
    Crear pila y árbol, inicialmente vacíos
    MIENTRAS posfija no este vacía y no hay errores HACER
       Extraer el primer termino de posfija (lo llamaremos E)
       SELECTOR E
        CASO E es operando :    Insertar E en la pila           
        CASO E es operador :    SI La pila tiene menos de dos elementos ENTONCES
                            ERROR 
                        SINO
                            Extraer elemento de la pila (lo llamaremos A2)
                            Extraer elemento de la pila (lo llamaremos A1)
                            Crear un árbol donde la raíz contenga al operador E,
                            el hijo izquierdo sea A1 y el hijo derecho sea A2
                            Insertar el árbol en la pila
                        FIN-SI
        DEFAULT: ERROR
       FIN-SELECTOR
    FIN-MIENTRAS
    SI pila vacía o con más de un elemento ENTONCES
        ERROR
    SINO
        Extraer elemento de la pila (lo llamaremos E)
        LLAMAR A Evaluar_Arbol(E);
        El resultado del algoritmo (el árbol de salida) es E      
    FIN-SI
    { Borrado de la pila, si se ha producido error }
    MIENTRAS pila no esté vacía HACER
        Extraer elemento de la pila
        Destruir elemento
    FIN-MIENTRAS
    Destruir pila
FIN
```

Pero al llegar al punto donde tengo que pasar los valores al árbol me funciona solo si es una operación sencilla como "34+" pero con otra operación mas añadida ejemplo 34+5* me da este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que cuando trato de pasarlo del arbol a la pila en el caso de la operacion 34+ me da el siguiente error en compilación **Cannot convert 'Nodo *' to 'char'**. comprendo que no puedo ingresar una esctuctura en un char pero no se como hacerlo con puntero dentro de la función.

***Código hasta el momento:***

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct nodo {
       char palabra;
       struct nodo *sgte;
       struct nodo *arbol;
       };

typedef struct nodo *Ptrpila;
typedef struct nodo *Tlista;


struct Nodo{
    char datoA;
   Nodo *izq;
   Nodo *der;
};

struct t_nodo{
    char datoP;
   t_nodo *sgte;
   t_nodo *izq;
   t_nodo *der;
};

//------------POSFIJO--------
void push(Ptrpila &,char);
char pop(Ptrpila &);
void agregar(Tlista &,char);
void destruir(Ptrpila &);
int  prioridadInfija(char );
int  prioridadPila(char );
void imprimir( Tlista &);
void balanceoSimbolos( Ptrpila &, char []);
//------------ARBOL-----------
Nodo *crearNodo(char);
void mostrarArbol(Nodo *,int);
void eliminarArbol(Nodo*&);

void meterPila(t_nodo*&, char);
void sacarPila(t_nodo*&, char&);

Nodo *arbol = NULL;
Nodo *arbolAux = NULL;


main(){
    Ptrpila p=NULL;
   Ptrpila M=NULL;
   t_nodo *pila = NULL;
   Tlista lista=NULL;
   char cad[100], salida,E,A2,A1;
   int tam, c,contador=0;

   do{
   cout<<"Operacion Infija:\n";
   gets(cad);
   if(M!=NULL)
    destruir(M);
      balanceoSimbolos(M,cad);
      }while(M!=NULL);
   tam=strlen(cad);
   for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
    if(cad[i]>=48&&cad[i]<=57||cad[i]=='.')
        agregar(lista,cad[i]);
    if(cad[i]=='+'||cad[i]=='-'||cad[i]=='*'||cad[i]=='/'||cad[i]=='('||cad[i]=='^'){
        if(p==NULL){
            push(p,cad[i]);
         }else{
            if(prioridadInfija(cad[i])>prioridadPila(p->palabra)){
                push(p,cad[i]);
            }else{
                if(prioridadInfija(cad[i])==prioridadPila(p->palabra)){
                    c=pop(p);
                  agregar(lista,c);
                  push(p,cad[i]);
               }else{
                    c=pop(p);
                  agregar(lista,c);
               }
            }
        }
      }
      if(cad[i]==')'){
        while(p->palabra!='('&&p!=NULL){
            c=pop(p);
            agregar(lista,c);
         }
         if(p->palabra=='(')
            c=pop(p);
         }
      }
      while(p!=NULL){
            c=pop(p);
         agregar(lista,c);
      }

      cout<<"Notacion Postfija:\n\n";
      while(lista!=NULL){

         E=lista->palabra;

         if(E>=48&&E<=57||E=='.'){
            meterPila(pila, E);
         }else{
           arbol=crearNodo(E);
           sacarPila(pila, E);
           A1=E;
           sacarPila(pila, E);
           A2=E;
           arbol->der=crearNodo(A1);
           arbol->izq=crearNodo(A2);
           arbolAux = arbol;
           meterPila(pila,arbol);
           cout<<"AQUI INICIA LA INSERCION AL ARBOL:\n";
           mostrarArbol(arbolAux,contador);
         }

         lista = lista->sgte;
      }cout<<"\n\n";

        system("pause");
        return 0;

}

//--------------INICIO POSTFIJA---------------------------

void push(Ptrpila &p,char a){
    Ptrpila q=new struct nodo;
    q->palabra=a;
    q->sgte=p;
    p=q;
}


char pop(Ptrpila &p){
    int n;
    Ptrpila aux;

    n=p->palabra;
    aux=p;
    p=p->sgte;
    delete(aux);
    return n;

}


void agregar(Tlista &lista,char a){
    Tlista t, q = new(struct nodo);

   q->palabra  = a;
   q->sgte = NULL;

   if(lista==NULL){
    lista = q;
   }else{
    t = lista;
      while(t->sgte!=NULL){
        t = t->sgte;
      }
        t->sgte = q;
   }
}

void destruir(Ptrpila &M)
{    Ptrpila aux;

     if(M !=NULL)
     {
         while(M!=NULL)
         {
             aux=M;
             M=M->sgte;
             delete(aux);
         }

      }
}

int prioridadInfija(char a){
    if(a=='^')
    return 4;
   if( a=='*')
    return 2;
   if( a=='/')
       return 2;
   if( a=='+')
       return 1;
   if( a=='-')
       return 1;
   if(a=='(')
       return 5;
}


int prioridadPila(char a){
    if(a=='^')
    return 3;
   if( a=='*')
      return 2;
   if( a=='/')
      return 2;
   if( a=='+')
      return 1;
   if( a=='-')
      return 1;
   if(a=='(')
      return 0;
}

void balanceoSimbolos( Ptrpila &p, char cad[])
{
     Ptrpila aux;
     int i = 0;

     while( cad[i] != '\0')
     {
            if( cad[i]=='(' || cad[i]=='[' || cad[i]=='{' )
            {
                 push( p, cad[i] );
            }
            else if( cad[i]==')' || cad[i]==']' || cad[i]=='}' )
            {
                 aux = p;

                 if(aux!=NULL)
                 {
                      if( cad[i]==')' )
                      {
                           if( aux->palabra == '(')
                              pop( p );
                      }
                      else if( cad[i]==']' )
                      {
                           if( aux->palabra == '[')
                              pop( p );
                      }
                      else if( cad[i]=='}' )
                      {
                           if( aux->palabra == '{')
                              pop( p );
                      }
                 }
                 else
                     push( p, cad[i] );
            }
            i++;
     }

     if(p==NULL)
         cout<<"\n\tBalanceo CORRECTO..."<<endl<<endl;
     else
         cout<<"\n\t Balanceo INCORRECTO, faltan simbolos de agrupacion..."<<endl;


}


//--------------------------INICIO ARBOL--------------------------------

void meterPila(t_nodo *&pila, char palabra){
    t_nodo *nodo = (t_nodo*)malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
   nodo->datoP =  palabra;
   nodo->sgte = pila;
   pila = nodo;

}

void sacarPila(t_nodo *&pila, char &n){
    t_nodo *aux=pila;
   n = aux->datoP;
   pila=aux->sgte;
   free(aux);
}

Nodo *crearNodo(char n){
    Nodo *nuevoNodo = new Nodo();
   nuevoNodo->datoA = n;
   nuevoNodo->izq = NULL;
   nuevoNodo->der = NULL;

   return nuevoNodo;
}


void mostrarArbol(Nodo *arbol, int contador){
    if(arbol == NULL){
    return;
   }else{
    mostrarArbol(arbol->der, contador+1);
      for(int i=0; i<contador; i++){
        cout<<"  ";
      }
      cout<<arbol->datoA<<endl;
      mostrarArbol(arbol->izq, contador+1);
   }
}

void eliminarArbol(Nodo *&arbol){
    if(arbol != NULL){
    eliminarArbol(arbol->izq);
      eliminarArbol(arbol->der);
      arbol = NULL;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he dicho en otros mensajes: C++ **no**  es C:

- Las cabeceras de sistema propias de C++ no acaban con `.h`. Y las heredadas de C deberían usar el prefijo `c`:

  ```
  #include <iostream> // sin .h, en este caso el .h no es portable
  #include <cstdlib>  // prefijo c
  #include <stdio.h>  // Esta no forma parte del estandar
  ```
- Para clases y estructuras no es necesario usar `typedef struct`:

  ```
  // esto
  struct nodo {
    char palabra;
    struct nodo *sgte;
    struct nodo *arbol;
  };
  // es equivalente a
  struct nodo {
    char palabra;
    nodo *sgte;
    nodo *arbol;
  };

  // y esto
  typedef struct nodo *Ptrpila;
  // es equivalente a
  typedef nodo* Ptrpila;
  ```
- C++ dispone de la clase `string` para la gestión de cadenas... opción mucho más segura y limpia que `char[]`:

  ```
  // evita esto
  char cad[100];
  // y usa esto
  std::string cad;
  ```
- C++ dispone de su propia librería de entrada salida con `cin` y `cout` (la cual usas en algunas partes del codigo):

  ```
  // evita esto
  gets(cad);
  // y usa esto
  std::cin >> cad;
  ```
- C++ dispone de su propio mecanismo de gestión de memoria con `new` y `delete`:

  ```
  // evita esto
  t_nodo *nodo = (t_nodo*)malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
  // y usa esto
  t_nodo* nodo = new t_nodo;
  ```
- C++ permite configurar los constructores y destructores de cada clase y estructura:

  ```
  // evita esto
  t_nodo *nodo = (t_nodo*)malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
  nodo->datoP =  palabra;
  nodo->sgte = pila;
  pila = nodo;

  //Y usa esto
  struct t_nodo
  {
    // ...

    t_nodo(char dato, nodo_t* sig)
      : datoP(dato), sgte(sig)
    { }
  };
  // ...
  t_nodo* nodo = new t_nodo(palabra,pila); // new invoca automaticamente el constructor
  pila = nodo;
  ```
- En C++ la función `main()` debe tener **obligatoriamente** un tipo de retorno:

  ```
  // No conforme al estandar
  main(){
  // Conforme al estandar
  int main(){
  ```
- En C++ las clases y funciones propias del estándar se suelen encontrar en el espacio de nombres `std`. O usas `using namespace std` o añades como prefijo `std::` a cada librería y clase (una más de las razones por las que tu codigo no compila).

Y aun con todo esto tu programa sigue sin compilar:

Primero los errores:

```
prog.cc:118:12: error: no matching function for call to 'meterPila'
           meterPila(pila,arbol);
           ^~~~~~~~~
```

La función tiene esta firma:

```
void meterPila(t_nodo*&, char);
```

Luego está claro que a un tipo `char` no le puedes pasar un tipo `Nodo*`... tu verás cómo debes corregir ese error.

También deberías prestar especial atención a los *warnings* puesto que no dicen tonterias:

```
prog.cc:68:18: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
    if(cad[i]>=48&&cad[i]<=57||cad[i]=='.')
       ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~


prog.cc:107:18: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
     if(E>=48&&E<=57||E=='.'){
        ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

Es decir, estás combinando operadores diferentes sin usar paréntesis para agruparlos con lo que se van a ejecutar de forma lineal sin distincciones... ¿estás seguro de que el resultado va a ser el esperado?

Tienes bastante por hacer antes de analizar el motivo por el cual tu programa no funciona correctamente... de hecho lo más correcto es decir que tu programa ahora mismo ni compila.